# react-native: Unable to update properties for view tag 35

Tags: react-native

Encountered an error, but don't know how to solve it? I don't know why this error occurs

How can I locate this error?

error message:

```
Unable to update properties for view tag 35
com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: ViewManager for tag 35 could not be found.
 View already dropped? false.
Last index 0 in last 100 views[I@1a66828d
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.resolveViewManager(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:119)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.updateProperties(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:142)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.synchronouslyUpdateViewOnUIThread(UIImplementation.java:290)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.synchronouslyUpdateViewOnUIThread(UIManagerModule.java:400)
    at com.facebook.react.animated.PropsAnimatedNode.updateView(PropsAnimatedNode.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.updateNodes(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:548)
    at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.runUpdates(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:457)
    at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$1.doFrameGuarded(NativeAnimatedModule.java:105)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:175)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:85)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:765)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

- System:

  - OS: Windows 10 10.0.18362
  - CPU: (8) x64
  - Memory: 2.67 GB / 15.85 GB
- Binaries:

  - Node: 12.16.1
  - Yarn: 1.22.4
  - npm: 6.13.4
  - Watchman: 20200604.181126.0
- SDKs:

  - Android SDK:
  - API Levels: 20, 23, 26, 27, 28, 29
  - Build Tools: 26.0.2, 27.0.3, 28.0.3, 29.0.3
  - System Images: android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
  - Android NDK: Not Found
- IDEs:

  - Android Studio: Version- 3.6.0.0 AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897
- Languages:

  - Java: 1.8.0_181
  - Python: Not Found
- npmPackages:

  - @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
  - react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0
  - react-native: 0.62.2 => 0.62.2
- npmGlobalPackages:

  - *react-native*: Not Found

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you are using `LayoutAnimation` API in react native.
if that's the case according to the [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation) you need to add this code before your jsx:

`if (Platform.OS === "android" && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
 }`

Comment: But I didn't use `LayoutAnimation`,  And react-native 0.61 are normal, but an error occurs in 0.62

Comment: I have this check added but still see this error when I edit and submit a form

Answer (score -1):

Wasted a lot of time trying to find the issue. It turns out one of the devs used the fontWeight attribute in styles. It worked fine on iOS but crashed on Android. Removing this fontWeight attribute fixed the crash for me on React-Native 72.0

Comment: we can't use fontWeight in styles ?